# HANA XS Advanced with sap-fibers while pushing app

Tags: node.js, npm, hana, hana-xs

I got error when I push my first XS app.

I took the app from GitHub (`myapp1`), then I added Node Modules, then I pushed it.

Here my error logs:

> Connected, dumping recent logs for app "myapp1-xsjs"
>
> 09.03.17 12:29:29.339 [STG/4] OUT Unpacking Node.js archive...
>
> 09.03.17 12:29:29.350 [STG/4] OUT Omitting npm install: node_modules directory is already present
>
> 09.03.17 12:29:29.350 [STG/4] OUT Copying SSL CA certificates...
>
> 09.03.17 12:29:37.153 [API] OUT Staged application "myapp1-xsjs" using buildpack "sap_nodejs_buildpack" creating droplet '7cf6beb7-4566-4591-aa19-0f015f9d16a0' (duration 14s).
>
> 09.03.17 12:29:37.873 [API] OUT Updated application "myapp1-xsjs" (state: STARTED -> STOPPED).
>
> 09.03.17 12:29:37.885 [API] OUT Stopping 1 instance(s) of application "myapp1-xsjs".
>
> 09.03.17 12:29:37.995 [API] OUT Updated application "myapp1-xsjs" (state: STOPPED -> STARTED).
>
> 09.03.17 12:29:38.007 [API] OUT Starting 1 instance(s) of application "myapp1-xsjs".
>
> 09.03.17 12:29:44.561 [API] OUT Starting new instance '175254a7-59f4-46f8-a87e-3b9c72a427e8' of application "myapp1-xsjs" (port 50011, index 0). 09.03.17 12:29:46.520 [APP/4-0] ERR /hana/shared/HPO/xs/ea_data/gisu546/executionroot/175254a7-59f4-46f8-a87e-3b9c72a427e8/app/node_modules/sap-xsjs/node_modules/sap-fibers/fibers.js:19 09.03.17 12:29:46.521 [APP/4-0] **`` ERR throw new Error('`'+ modPath+ '.node` is missing. Try reinstalling `node-fibers`?'); ``**
>
> 09.03.17 12:29:46.521 [APP/4-0] ERR ^ 09.03.17 12:29:46.521 [APP/4-0] ERR
>
> 09.03.17 12:29:46.521 [APP/4-0] ERR **`` Error: `/hana/shared/HPO/xs/ea_data/gisu546/executionroot/175254a7-59f4-46f8-a87e-3b9c72a427e8/app/node_modules/sap-xsjs/node_modules/sap-fibers/bin/linux-x64-LE-v8-5.1/fibers.node` is missing. Try reinstalling `node-fibers`? ``**
>
> 09.03.17 12:29:46.521 [APP/4-0] ERR at Object. (/hana/shared/HPO/xs/ea_data/gisu546/executionroot/175254a7-59f4-46f8-a87e-3b9c72a427e8/app/node_modules/sap-xsjs/node_modules/sap-fibers/fibers.js:19:8) 09.03.17 12:29:46.521 [APP/4-0] ERR at Module._compile (module.js:570:32) 09.03.17 12:29:46.521 [APP/4-0] ERR at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
>
> 09.03.17 12:29:46.521 [APP/4-0] ERR at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
>
> 09.03.17 12:29:46.521 [APP/4-0] ERR at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
>
> 09.03.17 12:29:46.521 [APP/4-0] ERR at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3) 09.03.17 12:29:46.521 [APP/4-0] ERR at Module.require (module.js:497:17) 09.03.17 12:29:46.521 [APP/4-0] ERR at require (internal/module.js:20:19) 09.03.17 12:29:46.521 [APP/4-0] ERR at Object. (/hana/shared/HPO/xs/ea_data/gisu546/executionroot/175254a7-59f4-46f8-a87e-3b9c72a427e8/app/node_modules/sap-xsjs/node_modules/sap-fibrous/lib/fibrous.js:6:11)
>
> 09.03.17 12:29:46.521 [APP/4-0] ERR at Object. (/hana/shared/HPO/xs/ea_data/gisu546/executionroot/175254a7-59f4-46f8-a87e-3b9c72a427e8/app/node_modules/sap-xsjs/node_modules/**sap-fibrous/lib/fibrous.js**:192:4) 09.03.17 12:29:52.866 [API] OUT Cleared instance '840d8505-2c30-4c93-8a04-21fb0139bb45' of application "myapp1-xsjs" (port 50012, pid 11684).

Can you please help with this ?

I don't know how can I fix it.

Best Regards

Houssem

Answer (score 1):

most likely you are using a newer node.js engine than what this version of sap-xsjs was released for. This causes depending native modules like sap-fibers to fail because no native binaries for the newer node API versions can be found in the shrinkwrapped modules.

Try forcing a lower node.js engine (0.12.x or 4.x) via the engines field in your app's package.json or try upgrading sap-xsjs to a newer version that supports node.js 6.9

Best